# Error react-native run-android app:instalDebug

Tags: android, reactjs, compiler-errors, react-native

I have a problem here, which is when I run the react-native run-android command and reach the app: install Debug, I get an error which is:

```
Execution failed for task ': app: install Debug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException
```

I do not know why the error could arise,
Hopefully someone can give reasons and solutions to why the error can occur.

Thank you very much

Comment: add your full error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Make sure your emulator or simulator are running and check the running adb device ,then
Try these commands ,to clear `cd android &&./gradlew clean` then run app using `cd .. && react-native run-android`

Feel free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your emulator or simulator are running

Clean your build folder and try again